# Container is connecting default cluster when trying to setup new ECS Cluster

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, ec2-ami

I am using following cloud formation script to create a new ECS cluster

```
*{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
  "Parameters":{
    "KeyName":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "Description":"Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the ECS instances."
    },
    "VpcId":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description":"Select a VPC that allows instances to access the Internet."
    },
    "SubnetId":{
      "Type":"List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description":"Select at two subnets in your selected VPC."
    },
    "DesiredCapacity":{
      "Type":"Number",
      "Default":"1",
      "Description":"Number of instances to launch in your ECS cluster."
    },
    "MaxSize":{
      "Type":"Number",
      "Default":"1",
      "Description":"Maximum number of instances that can be launched in your ECS cluster."
    },
    "InstanceType":{
      "Description":"EC2 instance type",
      "Type":"String",
      "Default":"t2.micro",
      "AllowedValues":[
        "t2.micro",
        "t2.small",
        "t2.medium",
        "t2.large",
        "m3.medium",
        "m3.large",
        "m3.xlarge",
        "m3.2xlarge",
        "m4.large",
        "m4.xlarge",
        "m4.2xlarge",
        "m4.4xlarge",
        "m4.10xlarge",
        "c4.large",
        "c4.xlarge",
        "c4.2xlarge",
        "c4.4xlarge",
        "c4.8xlarge",
        "c3.large",
        "c3.xlarge",
        "c3.2xlarge",
        "c3.4xlarge",
        "c3.8xlarge",
        "r3.large",
        "r3.xlarge",
        "r3.2xlarge",
        "r3.4xlarge",
        "r3.8xlarge",
        "i2.xlarge",
        "i2.2xlarge",
        "i2.4xlarge",
        "i2.8xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription":"Please choose a valid instance type."
    }
  },
  "Mappings":{
    "AWSRegionToAMI":{
      "us-east-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-0c65e6401a50512c5"
      }
    }
  },
  "Resources":{
    "ECSCluster":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::Cluster"
    },
    "EcsSecurityGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupDescription":"ECS Security Group",
        "VpcId":{
          "Ref":"VpcId"
        }
      }
    },
    "EcsSecurityGroupHTTPinbound":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupId":{
          "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
        },
        "IpProtocol":"tcp",
        "FromPort":"80",
        "ToPort":"80",
        "CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"
      }
    },
    "EcsSecurityGroupSSHinbound":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupId":{
          "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
        },
        "IpProtocol":"tcp",
        "FromPort":"22",
        "ToPort":"22",
        "CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"
      }
    },
    "EcsSecurityGroupALBports":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupId":{
          "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
        },
        "IpProtocol":"tcp",
        "FromPort":"31000",
        "ToPort":"61000",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId":{
          "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
        }
      }
    },
    "CloudwatchLogsGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
      "Properties":{
        "LogGroupName":{
          "Fn::Join":[
            "-",
            [
              "ECSLogGroup",
              {
                "Ref":"AWS::StackName"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "RetentionInDays":14
      }
    },
    "taskdefinition":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties":{
        "Family":{
          "Fn::Join":[
            "",
            [
              {
                "Ref":"AWS::StackName"
              },
              "-ecs-demo-app"
            ]
          ]
        },
        "ContainerDefinitions":[
          {
            "Name":"simple-app",
            "Cpu":"10",
            "Essential":"true",
            "Image":"httpd:2.4",
            "Memory":"300",
            "LogConfiguration":{
              "LogDriver":"awslogs",
              "Options":{
                "awslogs-group":{
                  "Ref":"CloudwatchLogsGroup"
                },
                "awslogs-region":{
                  "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                },
                "awslogs-stream-prefix":"ecs-demo-app"
              }
            },
            "MountPoints":[
              {
                "ContainerPath":"/usr/local/apache2/htdocs",
                "SourceVolume":"my-vol"
              }
            ],
            "PortMappings":[
              {
                "ContainerPort":80
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name":"busybox",
            "Cpu":10,
            "Command":[
              "/bin/sh -c \"while true; do echo '<html> <head> <title>Amazon ECS Sample App</title> <style>body {margin-top: 40px; background-color: #333;} </style> </head><body> <div style=color:white;text-align:center> <h1>Amazon ECS Sample App</h1> <h2>Congratulations!</h2> <p>Your application is now running on a container in Amazon ECS.</p>' > top; /bin/date > date ; echo '</div></body></html>' > bottom; cat top date bottom > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html ; sleep 1; done\""
            ],
            "EntryPoint":[
              "sh",
              "-c"
            ],
            "Essential":false,
            "Image":"busybox",
            "Memory":200,
            "LogConfiguration":{
              "LogDriver":"awslogs",
              "Options":{
                "awslogs-group":{
                  "Ref":"CloudwatchLogsGroup"
                },
                "awslogs-region":{
                  "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                },
                "awslogs-stream-prefix":"ecs-demo-app"
              }
            },
            "VolumesFrom":[
              {
                "SourceContainer":"simple-app"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Volumes":[
          {
            "Name":"my-vol"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ECSALB":{
      "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties":{
        "Name":"ECSALB",
        "Scheme":"internet-facing",
        "LoadBalancerAttributes":[
          {
            "Key":"idle_timeout.timeout_seconds",
            "Value":"30"
          }
        ],
        "Subnets":{
          "Ref":"SubnetId"
        },
        "SecurityGroups":[
          {
            "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ALBListener":{
      "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "DependsOn":"ECSServiceRole",
      "Properties":{
        "DefaultActions":[
          {
            "Type":"forward",
            "TargetGroupArn":{
              "Ref":"ECSTG"
            }
          }
        ],
        "LoadBalancerArn":{
          "Ref":"ECSALB"
        },
        "Port":"80",
        "Protocol":"HTTP"
      }
    },
    "ECSALBListenerRule":{
      "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule",
      "DependsOn":"ALBListener",
      "Properties":{
        "Actions":[
          {
            "Type":"forward",
            "TargetGroupArn":{
              "Ref":"ECSTG"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Conditions":[
          {
            "Field":"path-pattern",
            "Values":[
              "/"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ListenerArn":{
          "Ref":"ALBListener"
        },
        "Priority":1
      }
    },
    "ECSTG":{
      "Type":"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
      "DependsOn":"ECSALB",
      "Properties":{
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds":10,
        "HealthCheckPath":"/",
        "HealthCheckProtocol":"HTTP",
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds":5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount":2,
        "Name":"ECSTG",
        "Port":80,
        "Protocol":"HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount":2,
        "VpcId":{
          "Ref":"VpcId"
        }
      }
    },
    "ECSAutoScalingGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties":{
        "VPCZoneIdentifier":{
          "Ref":"SubnetId"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName":{
          "Ref":"ContainerInstances"
        },
        "MinSize":"1",
        "MaxSize":{
          "Ref":"MaxSize"
        },
        "DesiredCapacity":{
          "Ref":"DesiredCapacity"
        }
      },
      "CreationPolicy":{
        "ResourceSignal":{
          "Timeout":"PT300M"
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy":{
        "AutoScalingReplacingUpdate":{
          "WillReplace":"true"
        }
      }
    },
    "ContainerInstances":{
      "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties":{
        "ImageId":{
          "Fn::FindInMap":[
            "AWSRegionToAMI",
            {
              "Ref":"AWS::Region"
            },
            "AMIID"
          ]
        },
        "SecurityGroups":[
          {
            "Ref":"EcsSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "InstanceType":{
          "Ref":"InstanceType"
        },
        "IamInstanceProfile":{
          "Ref":"EC2InstanceProfile"
        },
        "KeyName":{
          "Ref":"KeyName"
        },
        "UserData":{
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                                "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                "         --resource ContainerInstances ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n",
                                "sudo yum -y update \n",
                                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                                "sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                "         --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
    },
    "service":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",
      "DependsOn":"ALBListener",
      "Properties":{
        "Cluster":{
          "Ref":"ECSCluster"
        },
        "DesiredCount":"1",
        "LoadBalancers":[
          {
            "ContainerName":"simple-app",
            "ContainerPort":"80",
            "TargetGroupArn":{
              "Ref":"ECSTG"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Role":{
          "Ref":"ECSServiceRole"
        },
        "TaskDefinition":{
          "Ref":"taskdefinition"
        }
      }
    },
    "ECSServiceRole":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties":{
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
          "Statement":[
            {
              "Effect":"Allow",
              "Principal":{
                "Service":[
                  "ecs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action":[
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path":"/",
        "Policies":[
          {
            "PolicyName":"ecs-service",
            "PolicyDocument":{
              "Statement":[
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                    "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
                    "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                    "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                    "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
                    "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress"
                  ],
                  "Resource":"*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ServiceScalingTarget":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget",
      "DependsOn":"service",
      "Properties":{
        "MaxCapacity":2,
        "MinCapacity":1,
        "ResourceId":{
          "Fn::Join":[
            "",
            [
              "service/",
              {
                "Ref":"ECSCluster"
              },
              "/",
              {
                "Fn::GetAtt":[
                  "service",
                  "Name"
                ]
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        "RoleARN":{
          "Fn::GetAtt":[
            "AutoscalingRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "ScalableDimension":"ecs:service:DesiredCount",
        "ServiceNamespace":"ecs"
      }
    },
    "ServiceScalingPolicy":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
      "Properties":{
        "PolicyName":"AStepPolicy",
        "PolicyType":"StepScaling",
        "ScalingTargetId":{
          "Ref":"ServiceScalingTarget"
        },
        "StepScalingPolicyConfiguration":{
          "AdjustmentType":"PercentChangeInCapacity",
          "Cooldown":60,
          "MetricAggregationType":"Average",
          "StepAdjustments":[
            {
              "MetricIntervalLowerBound":0,
              "ScalingAdjustment":200
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "ALB500sAlarmScaleUp":{
      "Type":"AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
      "Properties":{
        "EvaluationPeriods":"1",
        "Statistic":"Average",
        "Threshold":"10",
        "AlarmDescription":"Alarm if our ALB generates too many HTTP 500s.",
        "Period":"60",
        "AlarmActions":[
          {
            "Ref":"ServiceScalingPolicy"
          }
        ],
        "Namespace":"AWS/ApplicationELB",
        "Dimensions":[
          {
            "Name":"LoadBalancer",
            "Value":{
              "Fn::GetAtt" : [ 
                "ECSALB", 
                "LoadBalancerFullName"
              ] 
            }
          }
        ],
        "ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanThreshold",
        "MetricName":"HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count"
      }
    },
    "EC2Role":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties":{
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
          "Statement":[
            {
              "Effect":"Allow",
              "Principal":{
                "Service":[
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action":[
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path":"/",
        "Policies":[
          {
            "PolicyName":"ecs-service",
            "PolicyDocument":{
              "Statement":[
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[

                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ecs:CreateCluster",
                "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
                "ecs:Poll",
                "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
                "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
                "ecs:UpdateContainerInstancesState",
                "ecs:Submit*",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
                  ],
                  "Resource":"*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AutoscalingRole":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties":{
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
          "Statement":[
            {
              "Effect":"Allow",
              "Principal":{
                "Service":[
                  "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action":[
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path":"/",
        "Policies":[
          {
            "PolicyName":"service-autoscaling",
            "PolicyDocument":{
              "Statement":[
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                    "application-autoscaling:*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                    "ecs:DescribeServices",
                    "ecs:UpdateService"
                  ],
                  "Resource":"*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "EC2InstanceProfile":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties":{
        "Path":"/",
        "Roles":[
          {
            "Ref":"EC2Role"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs":{
    "ecsservice":{
      "Value":{
        "Ref":"service"
      }
    },
    "ecscluster":{
      "Value":{
        "Ref":"ECSCluster"
      }
    },
    "ECSALB":{
      "Description":"Your ALB DNS URL",
      "Value":{
        "Fn::Join":[
          "",
          [
            {
              "Fn::GetAtt":[
                "ECSALB",
                "DNSName"
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "taskdef":{
      "Value":{
        "Ref":"taskdefinition"
      }
    }
  }
}*
```

It got stuck in creating the service resource.

When I try to debug this, I found in the log on EC2 instance for ecs-agent docker: 
Registration completed successfully. I am running as 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:504254995642:container-instance/22a5c138-61b0-454f-b64e-f49a76fc6cbe' in cluster 'default'

Please can you suggest how can I configure it to 'my-cluster'

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster to /etc/ecs/ecs.config in userData script. That way you're telling ecs-agent to register itself to the correct ECS cluster.

- From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#ecs-agent-availparam).
- [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html) is an example of doing this.

Hope it helps.